# In conditional probability, why is $A|B$ not an event, if $A$ and $B$ are events?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I came across a set of lecture notes where it is remarked that in probability theory, when we have two events $A$ and $B$, although we use the notation $P(A|B)$ to denote the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$, this is not optimal since $A|B$ is not an event.

What is it that makes $A|B$ a non-event? and then what is $A|B$ exactly?

Comment: I read $P(A \mid B)$ as “the probability that event $A$ occurs given that event $B$ has occurred”. The expression $A \mid B$ has no meaning by itself. It is part of a larger phrase.

Comment: The relevant events are $A\cap B$ and $A$, as the definition of conditional probability indicates.

Comment: The $\mid B$ is something which provides context.  Here it is saying that the context in which we are asking about the probability of $A$ is not the usual context, but rather the context of where if the sample space were contracted to only include those outcomes who are elements of $B$, and having the probability measure adjust to compensate for that as well.

Comment: This is like how the $\pmod{12}$ is there as context for $5x \equiv 1\equiv 25\pmod{12}\implies x\equiv 5\pmod{12}$.  By itself it is not necessarily part of the "objects" involved in the expression, but rather there after the fact to change the way in which the rest of the expression is to be interpreted.

Comment: Apart from those notational matters it is helpful to realize that the conditional probability $P(B|A)=P(A\cap B)/P(A)$ of $B$ given $A$ equals the unconditional probability of $B$ *if and only if* $A$ and $B$ are independent. I find that very intuitive.